# Error in importing LibGDX generated project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, libgdx

I created a new project in Android Studio called My Application.

Using the libgdx set up .jar file which I downloaded, I created a new project called mygame.

However, when trying to import project into My Application, I got an Assertion Error: null.

I simply can't import the libgdx project!

```
null
java.lang.AssertionError
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.PreSyncChecks.attemptToUpdateGradleVersionInWrapper(PreSyncChecks.java:174)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.PreSyncChecks.ensureCorrectGradleSettings(PreSyncChecks.java:72)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.PreSyncChecks.canSync(PreSyncChecks.java:53)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter.doImport(GradleProjectImporter.java:430)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter.doImport(GradleProjectImporter.java:339)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter.importProject(GradleProjectImporter.java:320)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter.createProjectFileForGradleProject(GradleProjectImporter.java:142)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter.importProject(GradleProjectImporter.java:129)
at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidImportProjectAction.createImportWizard(AndroidImportProjectAction.java:165)
at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidImportProjectAction.selectFileAndCreateWizard(AndroidImportProjectAction.java:139)
at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidImportProjectAction.selectFileAndCreateWizard(AndroidImportProjectAction.java:121)
at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidImportProjectAction.actionPerformed(AndroidImportProjectAction.java:82)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:164)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:266)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:926)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:236)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:105)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:291)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:389)
at com.apple.laf.ScreenMenuItemCheckbox.itemStateChanged(ScreenMenuItemCheckbox.java:178)
at java.awt.CheckboxMenuItem.processItemEvent(CheckboxMenuItem.java:372)
at java.awt.CheckboxMenuItem.processEvent(CheckboxMenuItem.java:340)
at java.awt.MenuComponent.dispatchEventImpl(MenuComponent.java:343)
at java.awt.MenuComponent.dispatchEvent(MenuComponent.java:331)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

I tried deleting both of the .idea files in My Application and mygame. But it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You might have this error if you're using IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio with the Android Gradle plugin greater than v0.14.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134118

Try changing your gradle build version from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.4'
```

in build.gradle file